# Can't Run Project In Blend 4

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I opened up a WPF application I have and I'm able to build it without errors, however the option to run is disabled.  Also, when I open any xaml it says every control on the page is not supported in a WPF project.  I have been able to open this project before and I'm not sure what changed.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your project is a WPF Control Library rather than an application. The "Run Project" menu item will be disabled if your solution only contains a control library.

Not sure about the controls on the page not being supported though.